# VSLAM with ROS Kinetic

Tags: ros, vslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible that VSLAM will work with ROS Kinetic?

If not, is there a simple tweak that could be made to source code to allow this?

We want to integrate it with the [ZED ROS Wrapper](https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-ros-wrapper/blob/master/README.md) so we can initiate video feed with this device. Unfortunately, ZED ROS Wrapper only works with ROS Kinetic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252533/vslam-with-ros-kinetic/) by [aelkman](https://answers.ros.org/users/29125/aelkman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a rosbuild package, but that is still supported on Kinetic.

As to the code itself, you'll have to inspect the code to see what APIs are being used. If building the package fails, try and find out what is missing and what has been introduced to replace that.

That sounds more complicated then it probably is, but if you're new to ROS it might involve (quite) some learning.

We'll be happy to help, but won't do your work for you.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0